# C++ hotel occupancy and skipping 13th floor iteration coding project (not an IT student)

Tags: c++

For a project, I was asked to write a program that calculates the occupancy rate for a hotel. The program should start by asking the user how many floors the hotel has. A loop should then iterate once for each floor. In each iteration, the loop should ask the user for the number of rooms on the floor and how many of them are occupied. After all the iterations, the program should display how many rooms the hotel has, how many of them are occupied, how many are unoccupied, and the percentage of rooms that are occupied. The percentage may be calculated by dividing the number of rooms occupied by the number of rooms.

**Note**: It is traditional that most hotels do not have a thirteenth floor. The loop in this program should skip the entire thirteenth iteration.

My problem now is the program still asks for the number of occupied rooms although it does skip asking the number of room on the 13th floor.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iomanip.h>

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int roomsOnFloor = 0;
    float totalRooms = 0.00;
    int totalFloors = 0;
    int occupiedRoomsOnFloor = 0;
    float totalOccupiedRooms = 0.00;
    float percentOccupied = 0.00;

    cout << "Enter number of floors: ";
    cin >> totalFloors;

    while (totalFloors < 1)
    {
        cout << "Number of floors must be at least 1. Please re-enter ";
        cin >> totalFloors;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= totalFloors; i++)
    {
        if (i != 13)
        {
            cout << "Enter the number of rooms on the floor ";
            cin >> roomsOnFloor;

            while (roomsOnFloor < 10)
            {
                cout << "Number of rooms on floor must be at least 10. Please re-enter ";
                cin >> roomsOnFloor;
            }
        }
        cout << "How many rooms are occupied? ";
        cin >> occupiedRoomsOnFloor;

        totalRooms += roomsOnFloor;
        totalOccupiedRooms += occupiedRoomsOnFloor;
    }
    percentOccupied = (totalOccupiedRooms / totalRooms)*100;

    clrscr();
    cout << "The hotel has total of " << totalFloors << " floors\n";
    cout << "The hotel has total of " << totalRooms << " rooms\n";
    cout << "There are " << totalOccupiedRooms << " rooms occupied\n";
    cout << "There are " << totalRooms - totalOccupiedRooms << " empty rooms\n";
    cout << "Percentage of occupied rooms is " << setprecision(2) << percentOccupied << "%\n";

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: Yes, that's what ```if (i != 13)``` would do. :)

Comment: Next time, [ask the duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Also, you may want to put this before your loop: `if (totalFloors >= 13) ++totalFloors;`.

Comment: `#include<iostream.h>` The 1980s called....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is right way to do it.

If you are using it out of the `if` condition then it will not calculate the number of occupied rooms on 13 floors. You need put that in the `if` condition then it will be able to calculate `numberofoccupiedspace`:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iomanip.h>

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int roomsOnFloor = 0;
    float totalRooms = 0.00;
    int totalFloors = 0;
    int occupiedRoomsOnFloor = 0;
    float totalOccupiedRooms = 0.00;
    float percentOccupied = 0.00;

    cout << "Enter number of floors: ";
    cin >> totalFloors;

    while (totalFloors < 1)
    {
        cout << "Number of floors must be at least 1. Please re-enter ";
        cin >> totalFloors;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= totalFloors; i++)
    {
        if (i != 13)
        {
            cout << "Enter the number of rooms on the floor ";
            cin >> roomsOnFloor;

            while (roomsOnFloor < 10)
            {
                cout << "Number of rooms on floor must be at least 10. Please re-enter ";
                cin >> roomsOnFloor;
            }

            cout << "How many rooms are occupied? ";
            cin >> occupiedRoomsOnFloor;
            totalRooms += roomsOnFloor;
            totalOccupiedRooms += occupiedRoomsOnFloor;
        }                           
    }
    percentOccupied = (totalOccupiedRooms / totalRooms)*100;

    clrscr();
    cout << "The hotel has total of " << totalFloors << " floors\n";
    cout << "The hotel has total of " << totalRooms << " rooms\n";
    cout << "There are " << totalOccupiedRooms << " rooms occupied\n";
    cout << "There are " << totalRooms - totalOccupiedRooms << " empty rooms\n";
    cout << "Percentage of occupied rooms is " << setprecision(2) << percentOccupied << "%\n";

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it asks the number of rooms on the 13th floor because instructions for doing it are not in the `if`, so they're executed every time, even if floor is 13. You have to put everything in the `if`.

```
if (i != 13)
{

    cout << "Enter the number of rooms on the floor ";
    cin >> roomsOnFloor;

    while (roomsOnFloor < 10)
    {

        cout << "Number of rooms on floor must be at least 10. Please re-enter ";
        cin >> roomsOnFloor;
    }

    cout << "How many rooms are occupied? ";
    cin >> occupiedRoomsOnFloor;

    totalRooms += roomsOnFloor;
    totalOccupiedRooms += occupiedRoomsOnFloor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the number of occupied rooms outside of your `if`:

```
if (i != 13)
{
    cout << "Enter the number of rooms on the floor ";
    cin >> roomsOnFloor;

    //...
}

cout << "How many rooms are occupied? ";
cin >> occupiedRoomsOnFloor;
```

So obviously, you are only going to skip asking for the number of rooms, not the number of occupied rooms.

BTW: This is a good point to learn how to use a **debugger**. Stepping through this program would have made that obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
Because you ask for the number of occupied rooms outside the if block, you should change the code to:

    if (i != 13)
    {

        cout << "Enter the number of rooms on the floor ";
        cin >> roomsOnFloor;

        while (roomsOnFloor < 10)
        {

        cout << "Number of rooms on floor must be at least 10. Please re-enter ";
        cin >> roomsOnFloor;


        }

    cout << "How many rooms are occupied? ";
    cin >> occupiedRoomsOnFloor;
    }
```